# GLSL shaders won't compile and no error message on windows vista with an NVIDIA Geforce 9800 graphics card

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, shader, lwjgl

This is the part of the source code where the problem resides:

```
GL.createCapabilities();            
// Define the viewport dimensions
glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

int shaderProgram;
final String vertexShader = "#version 330 core\n in vec3 position; // The position variable has attribute position 0\n out vec4 vertexColor; // Specify a color output to the fragment shader\n void main()\n {\n gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0); // See how we directly give a vec3 to vec4's constructor\n vertexColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the output variable to a dark-red color\n }";

String fragmentShader = "#version 330 core\n in vec3 ourColor;\n"
                + "in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
                + "out vec4 color;\n"
                + "uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;\n"
                + "void main()\n"
                + "{\n"
                + "color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);\n"
                + "}";

int vertex, fragment;
// Vertex Shader
vertex = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GL20.glShaderSource(vertex, vertexShader);
GL20.glCompileShader(vertex);
// Fragment Shader
fragment = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
GL20.glShaderSource(fragment, fragmentShader);
GL20.glCompileShader(fragment);

//create program and bind shaders to program
shaderProgram = GL20.glCreateProgram();
GL20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertex);
GL20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragment);
GL20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
int vlength = GL20.GL_SHADER_SOURCE_LENGTH;
int iscompiled = GL20.glGetProgrami(fragment, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
if(iscompiled == GL_FALSE)
{
     System.out.println(glGetString(GL_VERSION));
     System.out.println("not compiled");
     System.out.println(GL11.glGetString(GL20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
     System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex));
     return;
}
int isLinked = GL20.glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS);
if(isLinked == GL_FALSE)
{
    System.out.println("failed linking");
    return;
}
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
 #version 330 core
 layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; // The position variable has attribute position 0

 out vec4 vertexColor; // Specify a color output to the fragment shader

 void main()
 {
     gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0); // See how we directly give a vec3 to vec4's constructor
     vertexColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the output variable to a dark-red color
 }
```

This is the fragment shader:

```
 #version 330 core
 in vec4 vertexColor; // The input variable from the vertex shader (same name and same type)

 out vec4 color;

 void main()
 {
     color = vertexColor;
 }
```

Both of the shaders don't compile. Niether the vertex or fragment shader. What needs to be fixed?
I am using the core profile of opengl version 3.3.
The operating system being run is windows vista home premium 64 bit.

Comment: Are you binding the color output using `glBindFragDataLocation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int iscompiled = GL20.glGetProgrami(fragment, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
```

You cannot query a *program* for compilation status. That is a property of each shader object seperately, and can be queried via `glGetShaderiv()`. Using `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` for `glGetProgramiv()` will just result in an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. After removing the faulty code with the glgetprogram() function, everything compiles and renders successfully.